# How to add a java library to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Am new to Eclipse, I am learning Java in Eclipse environment. Can any one explain how to add a Java library to Eclipse library ? ( I want to add a library to a location where all the libraries will be available, not to a specific project). So, that I can call those libraries in any project that I work on Eclipse environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe take a look at gradle, maven, ivy, buildr or similar

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve. Are you perhaps referring to the library management that Netbeans has? As in you can create a named library in the IDE, link a jar to it, javadocs, source perhaps, and then refer to that library in your project by the name you gave it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you want to add the same libraries to multiple project one easy way is create a userlibrary and add all the jar that you want

```
Window - Preferences - Java - Build Path - User Libraries
```

and later just right click on the individual projects and add the userlibrary to the build path of the individual projects

or alternatively

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs hit the default JRE (the checked one) and Edit.`

Then add jars that you want.

Comment: can i copy my .jar file into the location of "Installed JREs" (that is "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib") ??
so it will be like internal JARs ..... !

Comment: just Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs click on the checked jre and Edit then add external jars

Comment: I am having a problem while importing a library :

Error is :: (- Access restriction: The type ***** is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\*****.jar ) 
 how to get access for this library

Comment: which lib you are trying to import?what you are trying to achieve finally

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step :

> Right click on Project --> build-path --> click on configure build-path --> add external jars.